# What was the most dangerous programming mistake you have made in C?

Tags: c

I am an intermediate C programmer. If you have made any coding mistake that you came to know later that it was the most hazardous / harmful to the total application please share that code or description. I want to know this because in future I may come across such situations and I want to have your advice to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: One could argue that programming in C is actually a dangerous mistake ;-).

Comment: Only if you subscribe to the normative-religion school of programming that seems to be so popular these days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Few years ago I've got a call from my ex-colleague telling me about the problem he had to fix with my code, which was a router for credit card transactions.

Card number prefix consists of 6-digit BIN (Bank Identification Number) and extra few digits that banks use at own discretion, e.g. bank has BIN for Visa Classic card 456789, and reserve 2 extra digits to indicate sub-product, like 01 for student's card, 02 for co-branded card with local department store and so on. In this case card prefix, which is basically product identifier, becomes 8 digits long. When I coded this part, I decided that 9 digits "ought to be enough for everyone". It was running ok for 2 years until one day bank make a new card products with 10-digit-long prefix (have no idea why they needed it). Not too hard to imagine what has happened - router segfaulted, the whole system halted because it cannot function without transaction router, all ATMs of that bank (one of the biggest in the country) became non-operational for few hours, until problem was found and fixed.

I cannot post the code here firstly because I don't have it and secondly it is copyrighted by the company, but it is not hard to imagine the `strcpy()` without checking size of target buffer.

Just like `man strcpy` says:

> If the destination string of a
> strcpy() is not large enough  (that
> is, if  the  programmer  was  stupid
> or lazy, and failed to check the size
> before copying) then anything might
> happen.  Overflowing  fixed  length
> strings is a favorite cracker
> technique.

I was very embarrassed. But I've learned the lesson and do not forget (usually :) ) to check size of target buffer. I wouldn't recommend you to learn it the hard way - just develop a habit to check target buffer before `strcpy()` and `strcat()`.

Edit: good suggestion from Healthcarel - use `strncpy()` rather than `strcpy()`. It doesn't add trailing 0 but I usually use following macro to get around it:

`#define STRNCPY(A,B,C) do {strncpy(A,B,C); A[C] = 0; } while (0)`

Comment: That's why i always use strncpy as suggested in my man strcpy.

Comment: @Heathcarel, a function that omits the null-termination, if the buffer is too small isn't much better. Better use strlcpy or snprintf().

Comment: The strlcpy/g_strlcpy-family from BSD and glib is useful here -- they always take a destination buffer size and won't write beyond it.

Comment: @Healthcarel: Firstly, `strncpy` is not a replacement for `strcpy` (it is not even the same family of functions). `strlcpy` is the proper function. Secondly, truncating the string (with any function) is not a solution for the original problem. Quite the opposite, truncating the string would've resulted in a much bigger disaster than what this poster describes. In fact, they are lucky the system *crashed* instead of continuing to run in an invalid state.

Answer (score 26):

```
if (c = 1) // insert code here
```

Comment: +1 - there is an idiom you might see around (1 == c) that people use to avoid this error.  It's one of the classics.

Comment: Upvoted - a very common mistake. Newer compilers will warn about it. Also, one can avoid it by putting the constant on the left, as in "if (1 == c)", which will make a typo like this an error.

Comment: D'oh! That'll teach me to read the other comments before adding my own. :-)

Comment: I often hear the statement that this is a common mistake, but almost never find people (other than online) who have actually made it.  I, for one, find (1 == c) to be terrible on the readability scale and avoid using it like the plague.

Comment: @DocMax i don't like it as well, especially taking in account that compiler will warn about it (at least compilers i used).

Comment: On the 'constant on left of equality` idiom, older compilers, lint, etc did not pick this up.  Many, MANY hours have been lost trying to find this type of bug.  It is counter-intuitive to read at first, but I find them about the same after 10+ years of C and C-like language development.  I use it.

Comment: Is there a "standard" answer on how to address (x = y) vs. (x == y) when both are variables?  I've seen none.

Comment: DocMax, i find and fix this kind of error every other month. And sometimes it's the other way around, "==" instead of "=" :)

Comment: It is sad where lots of time in software engineering has gone. Finding out wrong operators, misplaced spaces, converting datetimes, locales, and so on...

Comment: I don't like (1 == c) either, but I have written (c = 1) accidentally a few times. I'm glad nobody's life depended on it.

Comment: I do the same thing sometimes, even on the web dev side. PHP loooooves infinite loops.

Answer (score 21):

```
if(a == true);
{
  //Do sth when it is true. But it is allways executed.
}
```

**Edit**: Another variant of the same mistake.

```
for(i=0; i<max_iterations;i++);
{
  //Do sth but unexpectedly only once
}
```

Comment: ohhohhooo... i took 2 minutes to find that semicolon there.really.
this is the funniest mistake and dangerous too. this is why i am addicted to stackoverflow. i got really good examples thank u once again

Comment: I still don't see why the compiler just doesn't flag that as an error... if(condition); warning/error: statement/block missing.

Comment: It does flag a warning on VS2008 default settings ...but not everyone takes warnings seriously.

Comment: There's no statement missing, really; it's just the empty statement.  After that, there's a block.

Comment: The Digital Mars C compiler does a warning for these, and the D programming language makes them out and out errors. (To have a null statement, use { } )

Comment: The name of this mistake is "Allman style indenting". Use K&R.

Comment: There's a second mistake in that first example - in C you should never write `if(a == true)` - it should always be `if (a)`.

Answer (score 13):

It has been a long time, but some things you never forget ;-).

- forget the `\0` at the end of a string.
- allocate n characters for a string with n characters.
- forgetting the break in a switch statement.
- 'creative' macro use.

Comment: @Constantin, C-strings (well char* ) are null terminated .. and \0 is the null terminator escape code.

Comment: +1 for "Creative macro use"... ha ha ha!!! And if it was possible, I would give one more +1 for the quotes around the word creative !!!

Answer (score 7):

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
  //code here
  //code added later
```

Note that the later added code is not in the for loop.

Comment: so flower brackets should be provided for every for

Comment: true. That's what i'm doing now.

Comment: No, you should switch to python where indenting controls flow :-).

Comment: @Pax I think that indentation as a scope declaration is possibly one of the worst features of python esp. when you're reading it away from the screen.

Comment: @stephbu in practice, it has never caused me any problems and I've come to like it now.

Answer (score 5):

Uninitialized data.

Comment: Hit me across the face more than I'd like to admit. Everytime I see `foobar = 100283828` in gdb, I double check my declarations.

Comment: If this is the most dangerous programming mistake you ever made, you must be genius!

Answer (score 4):

The most dangerous thing I ever did in C was trying to write code which managed my own memory.  Effectively, this means the **most dangerous thing I ever did in C was write C code**.  (I hear that you can get around it these days.  Hip hip for sanity.  Use those approaches whenever appropriate!)

- I don't write paging algorithms -- OS geeks do that for me.
- I don't write database caching schemes -- database geeks do that for me.
- I don't build L2 processor caches -- hardware geeks do that for me.

And I do *not* manage memory.

Someone else manages my memory for me -- someone who can design better than I can, and test better than I can, and code better than I can, and patch when they make critical security-compromising mistakes which only get noticed 10 years later because **absolutely everyone** who attempts to allocate memory fails some of the time.

Answer (score 4):

system() with some user-supplied string in the argument.  Same goes for popen().

Use exec*() instead.

Of course, this is not unique to C.

Comment: Not on Windows! Quoth MSDN:
"Spaces embedded in strings may cause unexpected behavior; for example, passing _exec the string "hi there" will result in the new process getting two arguments, "hi" and "there". ... You can avoid this by quoting the string: "\"hi there\""."

Comment: Sounds bad, what if the user supplied string contains a quote?

Comment: If the user supplied string contains a quote, there’s no correct thing to do. Command instantiation and argument handling on Windows is a disaster. Calls to system() and exec() are mapped to CreateProcess(), and if you look at the documentation for that function you’ll see it takes a single argument for the whole command line, not separate parameters. That whole command line is passed to the new process, and parameters must be separated out by the application, so theoretically the argument handling behaviour can differ between applications.

Answer (score 3):

You should worry more about little mistakes. Big/spectacular mistakes are usually documented in books (with reasons why they are bad, alternative approaches etc.).

It's the little design/coding mistakes that get to you, because they tend to add up.

So my advice is to try and read the books Kernighan wrote or co-authored ("The C Programming Language", "Practice of Programming" etc.) because they are full of common-sense (common for experienced C programmers) advice and list principles that are very useful in avoiding both small and big mistakes.

They also list many potential big mistakes, so they answer your initial question.

Answer (score 3):

I take the definition of dangerous as "we may ship with that bug and discover only years later when it's to late":

```
char* c = malloc(...);
.
.
.
free(c);  
.
.
.
c[...] = ...;
```

or

```
// char* s is an input string
char* c = malloc(strlen(s));
strcpy(c, s);
```

But if you write multiplatform (not limited to x86/x64) this is also great:

```
char* c = ...;
int i = *((int*)c); // <-- alignment fault
```

And if your buffer comes from an untrusted source.. basically most code around is dangerous.

But, anyway, in C it's so easy to shoot yourself in the foot, that a topic about shot feet could go around the thousands of pages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in agreement with Pat Mac here (despite his downvoting). The most dangerous thing you can do in C is simply to use it for something important.

For example, a sensible language would by default check array bounds and stop your program immediately (raise an exception or something) if you try to wander outside of it. Ada does this. Java does this. Tons of other languages do this. Not C. There are entire hacking industries built around this flaw in the language.

One personal experience with this. I worked with a company that ran a network of flight simulators, tied together with reflective (shared) memory hardware. They were having a nasty crash bug they couldn't track down, so our two best engineers got sent up there to track it down. It took them 2 months.

It turned out that there was an off-by-one error in a C loop on one of the machines. A competent language would have stopped things right there of course, but C let it go ahead and write a piece of data in the next location past the end of the array. This memory location happened to be used by another machine on the network which passed it to a *third* machine, which used the (garbage) value as an array index. Since this system was also coded in C, it didn't care either that it was indexing way outside of its array, and trashing semi-random memory locations in its program.

So, due to a lack of array bounds checking, a simple easy to make off-by-one bug caused random crashes in a computer two entire hops away from the source of the bug! Cost to the company: 4 man-months of their best engineers' time, plus however much was spent by other engineers and support personnel, plus all the downtime from the simulators in question not working right.

Comment: And Ada and Java were written in what language?

Comment: I can't speak for Java, but I know most compilers are written in the very language they compile (the process is called bootstrapping). If you don't believe me, go check out the code for gcc-ada. It's in Ada.

Comment: I don't think C is a bad language (I love it), it's just a dangerous language that doesn't have training wheels. Too many students today go straight to Java/.NET without understanding it. I'm still surprised though at the amount of new critical systems being written in C++.

Comment: C fans like to talk about "training wheels". I think of it more like C being a chainsaw with no guards, chain brakes, chain catcher, or safety throttle, and an old-fashioned kickback-prone chain.

Answer (score 2):

When a pointer is first allocated, it does not have a pointee.

The pointer is "uninitialized"

A dereference operation on a bad pointer is a serious runtime error.

If you are lucky, the dereference operation will crash or halt immediately (Java behaves this
way).

If you are unlucky, the bad pointer dereference will corrupt a random area of
memory, slightly altering the operation of the program so that it goes wrong some
indefinite time later. Each pointer must be assigned a pointee before it can support
dereference operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(a)
{ 
   // code - where 'a' never reaches 0 :( 
}
```

Comment: How is this dangerous? Infinite loops almost always get detected and fixed quickly compared to other mistakes.

Comment: @Brain - That statement is really funny when you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Two things comes to mind.
Ths first was a function in embedded C (MCU) i tried to have some restrictions on an timer value as a entered a function. so I wrote

```
if(55000 < my_var < 65000)
```

My ida was to check like this:

```
if( (55000<my_var) < 65000)
```

But this is the equivilant or the result

```
if( (55000<my_var) || (my_var<65000))
```

and the result ended up that the if test was always true.

The secound was a pointer mistake. (simplyfied presented here)

```
get_data(BYTE **dataptr)
{ 
  ubyte* data = malloc(10);
  ... code ...
  *dataptr = &data[1];
}

 main()
 {
   BYTE *data
   get_data(&data);
   free(data);
 }
```

Thus resulting in a loss of 1 byte of memory for each time the `get_data()` function was called

Comment: I am afraid you wrote another mistake here. "But this is the equivilant". No, it is not. This is equivalent to (55000 < my_var) < 65000, which is comparing a boolean to 65000 - which always yields true.

Comment: Not to mention I doubt free would work with an offset from the original pointer. It was probably failing outright, loosing you the 10 bytes + whatever overhead the heap had (~32 on most isn't it?)

Comment: Simon Buchan: Depends on the system you are working in. My linux system did not catch this but I an not running any large memory manager. So I ended up consumin all available memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous historical example (not something I did), but

```
double d;      // d gets populated with a large number from somewhere
short s = d ;  // overflow
```

[led to](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/ariane.html) [the explosion and total loss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYUrqdUyEpI) of [an Ariane V rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501).

Answer (score 1):

Using non-limited string functions such as strcpy() or strcmp(), instead of safe versions like strncpy() and strncmp().

Comment: do you mean strcat instead of strcmp? Because strcmp is safe as long as your strings are null-terminated, which should always the case when you use strings.

Comment: It *should* always be the case. But it's not safe to assume that should == will, especially if you're comparing strings that some other code is passing to yours.

Comment: well then you can add all str* functions to your list, because they all assume that the strings are null-terminated.

Comment: It's meant as an example, not an exhaustive list.

Comment: `strncpy` is no safer than `strcpy`. It's worst fault is that, when it fails, it gives you something that _isn't_ a C string (ie, not null-terminated). The next time you try to do something stringy with it (like strcmp or strlen), you will hit undefined behaviour territory.

Answer (score 1):

Passing virtual address to the DMA engine was a worst one, not exactly C related, but i assume that 99% of DMA related stuff written in C so it's kind of match. 
This small error lead to memory corruption that took me 1.5 month to find.

Answer (score 1):

switch case with no break.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I love vim snippets. :)

Answer (score 1):

Having been a Lisp programmer, I was used to indenting closing braces, as in:

```
(cond
    ((eq a foo)(bar ...
        ....
        ))
    )
```

and I carried this into C programming:

```
if (a == foo){
    bar(...);
    ....
    }
```

Then I got on a good-size project in C, and another programmer had to make changes in the vicinity of my code. He mis-read my closing brackets, and freed some memory too early. This caused an extremely subtle bug that happened at crunch time. When it was found, he got blamed, badly. But you could say it was my fault. That was not fun, to say the least.

Comment: This is exactly why you should try to match the coding style already in use in whatever project you’re working on.

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting architecture constraints and happily memcpy()ing into the memory mapped I/O area on a microcontroller. The magic smoke was released from the test rig.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with dynamically allocated 2D arrays and I instead of free()'ing N rows, I decided to free M columns. This was fine for smaller inputs where N == M but on large inputs, I only free()'d 50% of what I allocated.

*shrug*

Live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look after are array bounds. If you go out of bounds, with bad luck you may end up overwriting memory that is used for other data.

One nasty bug related to this was going out of bounds for a static array variable in a function. That ended up as a function changing values of the local variables of the calling function. That wasn't so straight-forward to debug..

Answer (score 0):

I remember two blunders:

1. returning address of an auto variable from within a function in which it was created;
2. copying string to an uninitialised and unallocated pointer to char.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
```

Me thinking C supports string natively (using Metroworks codewarrior, about 8 years ago).

I did this, for a final project of about 15,000 lines of code. I used this library to do everything relating to strings(appending, splitting, etc.) Only to have the TA's not able to compile any bit of my assignment(using GCC.)

Little did i learn that metroworks had created their own string library. I failed that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (importantvar = importantfunction() == VALID_CODE)
```

This is when I meant this:

```
if ((important var = importantfunction()) == VALID_CODE)
```

This led to many hours of debugging troubles when I assumed it worked like the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to put `;` at the end. 
 Excess `}`.
 Mistakenly typed a `,`

These makes me go nuts for hours finding what stuffs have gone wrong with my codes.